# Cannot move (malware) message to junk or trash - Mac Mail

Tags: email, malware

Got a malware attachment in an email I knew better than to open. My Sophos auto-protection caught it, too, and named it "DocExp-AC".
However, if I tried to right-click to move it to Junk (in preparation to Erase Junk), it appeared to be moved, but then I got a Mac Mail error message that it could not be moved [repeat step several times]. This caused it to actually appear in both Inbox and Junk.
Same behavior when tying it move it directly to Trash.
Somehow the bad actors have figured out a way to prevent us from easily deleting the email.
I've learned to quick-as-I-can stop TimeMachine from auto-backup as once a bad actor gets backed up its a major PITA to delete.

Answer (score 2):

As it was a IMAP account I opened the account via the web interface. I was able to delete it completely from the server. When my Mac subsequently fetched new mail it recognized it as having been moved to Trash at the server and moved the local copy to Trash. I was then able to delete it from my Mac Mail Trash (though I had to right-click it twice.) A Sophos Fast System Scan reports no threats found. Whew!